# My data is not getting updated in real time

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-fullstack

//This is the onSnapshot code.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import {
  getFirestore, collection, onSnapshot,
  addDoc, deleteDoc, doc,
} from 'firebase/firestore'


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBb5AHBfb5EFH0tSlQmz0_SqVnjsrCmk7Q",
    authDomain: "fir-9-dojo-546aa.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "fir-9-dojo-546aa",
    storageBucket: "fir-9-dojo-546aa.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "516827056470",
    appId: "1:516827056470:web:2e81ae062de6dcda8c6ef7"
  };
  // init firebase
initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

// init services
const db = getFirestore()

// collection ref
const colRef = collection(db, 'books')

// realtime collection data
onSnapshot(colRef, (snapshot) => {
  let books = []
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    books.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
  })
  console.log(books)
})

// adding docs
const addBookForm = document.querySelector('.add')
addBookForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  addDoc(colRef, {
    title: addBookForm.title.value,
    author: addBookForm.author.value,
  })
  .then(() => {
    addBookForm.reset()
  })
})

// deleting docs
const deleteBookForm = document.querySelector('.delete')
deleteBookForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const docRef = doc(db, 'books', deleteBookForm.id.value)

  deleteDoc(docRef)
    .then(() => {
      deleteBookForm.reset()
    })
})
```

[Before refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vcau.png)

[After refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5BNk.png)

I tried to collect the real time data . so , i was using onSnapshot() from firebase , but the data is not getting updated in real time. It is only getting updated when I refresh the page. I want it to get updated in real time without refreshing the page.

Comment: From reading the code, the `console.log(books)` should actually already fire in realtime. Is that not happening?